# Python registers same index for duplicate items in list, how to find exact index

Tags: python, loops, indexing

**Problem:**

I want to write 'long' or 'short' in a list of strings right after a stock ticker item. But if there are duplicate items in the list it doesn't add the word 'long' or 'short'. When I print out the index it gives '2' for both items. What is going wrong and how can I remedy this? Thanks.

**Result:**

```
['Roman', '16.06.2021', **'HARVIA.HE', 'long', 'HARVIA.HE', 'test'**]
```

**Code:**

```
for list in cleanUserInput:
    list.insert(3, 'test')
    list.insert(5, 'test')
    list.insert(7, 'test')
    for item in list:
        if '.HE' in item:
            longShortIndex = list.index(item) + 1
            if item.startswith('-'):
                list[longShortIndex] = 'short'
                cleanTicker = item[1 : : ]
                list[index] = cleanTicker
                if cleanTicker not in tickers: tickers.append(cleanTicker)
            else:
                list[longShortIndex] = 'long'
                if item not in tickers: tickers.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code correctly returns the index of FIRST OCCURENCE of item. In this case you would better loop through the list index instead of list items.
Also avoid using the name 'list' as it's already used by Python (I have replaced it by 'l')
Try the following:

```
for l in cleanUserInput:
    l.insert(3, 'test')
    l.insert(5, 'test')
    l.insert(7, 'test')
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if '.HE' in l[i]:
            longShortIndex = i + 1
            if l[i].startswith('-'):
                l[longShortIndex] = 'short'
                cleanTicker = l[i][1 : : ]
                l[i] = cleanTicker
                if cleanTicker not in tickers: tickers.append(cleanTicker)
            else:
                l[longShortIndex] = 'long'
                if l[i] not in tickers: tickers.append(l[i])
```